# can we change the gps values of a mobile device?

Tags: java, android, iphone, asp.net

I am trying to test a Location aware application on Android and iPhone in which I need to go to different locations.

Is it possible to mask/change the GPS location of the smart phone in which the GPS app is running using some code in.Net /Java? This is to make testing easier...

Comment: try googling using mock locations in android

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Sheena well they have obviously put no effort into finding out how to do it so why should people go through the effort of trying to answer it when all they need to do is google it and the answer is right there?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure something like that would require hacking the onboard GPS chip. The easiest solution here would be to actually have your app mock the GPS coordinates instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use a free 'Fake GPS' application from the Google Play Store for that purpose. I'm sure there are several available on both your target platforms